# Type of null literal in C#

Tags: c#, null

I have a query about type of null. 
I have a small program can anyone tell me about this.

```
public class TestApplication
{
    public void ShowText(object  ob)
    {
        Console.Write("Inside object");
    }
    public void ShowText(string str)
    {
        Console.Write("Inside string");
    }
    public void ShowText(int i)
    {
        Console.Write("Inside int.");
    }
    public void ShowText(char c)
    {
        Console.Write("Inside Character");
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new TestApplication().ShowText(null);            
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Why it call the string function. 
Is it means the type of null is string.
It might look a foolish conclusion but I am not able to find the region why it is calling the function of string.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Your question about the type of the null literal is answered here: [What is the type of null literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204578/what-is-the-type-of-null-literal)

But that doesn't really matter when talking about overload resolution. The actual null value itself will automatically be converted to whatever type it ends up as.

As for why the `string` overload is called:

1. You can't pass null as `int` and `char` parameters as they're value types, so those two overloads are out. (They could have been candidates had you made them nullable `int?` and `char?` types, but I won't go into that.)
2. Between the two other overloads taking reference types, `string` is a more specific type than `object`. That is, it derives from (and is therefore implicitly convertible to) `object`. Further, from the following section in the C# language spec (emphasis mine):

   > *7.5.3.5 Better conversion target*
   >
   > Given two different types `T1` and `T2`, `T1` is a better conversion target than `T2` if at least one of the following holds:
   >
   > - *An implicit conversion from `T1` to `T2` exists, and no implicit conversion from `T2` to `T1` exists*
   > - ...

Thus, the `string` overload is chosen as the best fit.

Comment: Can you give my any region why it is more specific. I am not able to understand. Is it means that the type of null is string?

Comment: @krshekhar: no, it has any type. To force object do: `(object)null`

Comment: From the linked answer, from C# 3.0 on the `null type` is removed from the specification, so null basically has no type.

Comment: It's more specific because having ruled out all except the `object` and `string` options, the compiler then notes that whenever it can pass something to the form that takes `string` it can pass it to the form that takes `object`, but not the other way around (think about if the value was a non-null string, and how you'd want that to be the form used even though the other was possible). If you'd another method that took another reference type then the compiler wouldn't be able to choose between them.

Answer (score 6):

`null` can fit to any reference-type. and hence is a very good example for polymorphism.

lets say you have a `Vehicle` class. you create three more class `Two-Wheeler`, `Three-Wheeler`, `Four-Wheeler`.

if latter 3 class `extends` `Vehicle` class; it is called `Vehicle` is specified into those three categories.

So, given a value, say car, more specific fit to this value is `Four-Wheeler`.

Similar is the case with `null`. it can fit to either `Object` OR `String`; but more specific match is `String`.

Lets see how compiler thinks (specific to your code only) when it sees a call to `ShowText(null)` method

1. Find `ShowText` method.
2. Oh, I've found 4, methods, which one to call?!!
3. Lets see what argument is passed, hmm .. it's `null`.
4. Find `ShowText` method which has reference type as argument. all overloads with primitive arguments are ignored.
5. Oh No ... i can match it to eithe `string` OR `object`.
6. Which is more specific. i.e which comes first in inheritance hierarchy from below.
7. Hurray .. found it .. it's `string` .. lets call it.

And, for an exercise if you want to undestand that what will happen if compiler finds at step 6 mor than one matches ... define a ShowText(string[] vals) and see yourself.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of the overload resolution in C#, it does not prove that the type of the `null` is string.

`null` is a special value that is included in the domain of any reference type, it basically determines that there is not a valid reference. As such, it can be a `string`, an `int?`, an `object` etc, etc.

You can even cast `null` to any reference type, to get a "correctly" typed `null`, e.g. you must cast null if it's used as a value in a `?` operator

```
int? value = (i > 0) ? i : null; // does not compile
int? value = (i > 0) ? i : (int?)null; //works
```