# Assigning `null` value to Nullable<DateTime> with single line 'if'

Tags: c#, datetime, null

I have a Class like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> ApplicationDate { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

Now I'm trying to fill an object of `MyClass` like this

```
DataTable dt = DBHelper.GetDataTable(sql, conn);
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[0];

MyClass oMyClass = new MyClass();
oMyClass.Id = (int)dr["Id"];
oMyClass.ApplicationDate = dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value ? null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]); 
//Above line gives an error
....
```

Assigning of Application Date value gives an error

`Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'System.DateTime'`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You need to cast `null` to `DateTime?`:

```
oMyClass.ApplicationDate = dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value 
    ? (DateTime?)null 
    : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]);
```

This is because of the way the compiler determines the resulting type of the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); the behavior is by design:

> Either the type of first_expression and second_expression must be the
>   same, or an implicit conversion must exist from one type to the other.

Since `null` by itself [is of null type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204578/what-is-the-type-of-null-literal) and thus there is no conversion from or to it, you need to help the compiler by casting.

Comment: wouldn't `null` have to be casted as well? It seems the error message relates to `null` and `System.DateTime`.

Comment: @Default: Yes `null` is what needs to be cast, my bad.

Comment: I get `Nullable object must have a value` when doing something similar to this and these answers on this page, including the `(DateTime?)null` cast.

Comment: @vapcguy that must mean "something similar to this" is incorrect then. For example, you cannot blindly access `Value` on the resulting object, that's the whole point of `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: @Jon, Only difference was I was testing a string for empty, instead of `dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value`. Everything else was the same. Turned out it was hitting on a line after it, though, where I was assigning my variable's `.Value` (my equivalent of the  `DateTime<Nullable> ApplicationDate` above - I just called it another name) to an `OracleParameter` for my `OracleCommand`, which was of `OracleDbType.Date` and the database field was, indeed, set to accept nulls. But I found out what was happening. You cannot assign `(DateTime?)null` to an Oracle `DATE` field - it has to be `DBNull.Value`.

Answer (score 7):

```
oMyClass.ApplicationDate =
    dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value ?
    (DateTime?)null :
    Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]);
```

All the compiler knows is that one thing evaluates to a `null` and the other evaluates to a `DateTime`. The compiler complains because it can't convert from one to the other so it's up to you to cast them to something that can be both values.

Note that `DateTime?` is short for `Nullable<DateTime>`.
Also note that you only need to cast the null value as there is an implicit conversion between `DateTime?` and `DateTime` so the compiler can do that conversion its self.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
oMyClass.ApplicationDate = 
    dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : 
                                     Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]);
```

You can also apply the cast to the last expression.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `default` which will assign the default value of an uninitialized Type.

```
oMyClass.ApplicationDate = dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value ? default(Nullable<DateTime>) : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]);
```

More examples

```
bool isHappy = default(bool); //isHappy = false
int number = default(int); //number = zero
string text = default(text); // text = null
MyObject myObject = default(MyObject); // myObject = null
DateTime? date = default(DateTime?); //date = null
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to convert "null" into Nullable

Try this code:

```
oMyClass.ApplicationDate = dr["ApplDate"] == DBNull.Value ? (DateTime?)null : Convert.ToDateTime(dr["AppDate"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)null;
```

or

```
Nullable<DateTime> dt = (Nullable<DateTime>)null;
```