# How to distinct between a null array and the null reference when passed as parameter on a method expecting params T[]

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, generics, null

I have created this test code [here](http://dotnetfiddle.net/ePTe1V). I'd like to distinct between the `null` reference, passed in `b1`'s call, and the null array, passed in `b3`'s call. As it is, both are being treated as a null array, but I'd like that when the `null` reference is passed, the method gets an array with a `null` value inside (just like it would work in `.In("foo")`. Is it possible? Maybe with a method overload, or something?

Restrictions: a) must use the params keyword; b) no change in the way the method is invoked (I don't
    want to dinstinct just by changing `b1`'s call to `.In(string[] { null })` for example).

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string nullString = null;
        List<string> nullList = null;
        string[] nullArray = null;

        //Calls bool In<T>(T value, T[] values)
        //Returns true.
        bool b1 = nullString.In(null);  
        //Calls bool In<T>(T value, IEnumerable<T> values)
        //Returns false
        bool b2 = nullString.In(nullList);
        //Calls bool In<T>(T value, T[] values)
        //Returns true, but I'd like it to return false, as above
        bool b3 = nullString.In(nullArray); 

        Console.WriteLine("nullString.In(null): {0}", b1);
        Console.WriteLine("nullString.In(nullList): {0}", b2);
        Console.WriteLine("nullString.In(nullArray): {0}", b3);
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool In<T>(this T value, params T[] values)
    {
        bool found = false;
        if (value == null && values == null)
            found = true;
        else
            found = In(value, (IEnumerable<T>)values);
        return found;
    }

    public static bool In<T>(this T value, IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        bool found = false;
        if (values != null)
        {
            foreach (T val in values)
            {
                if (Equals(value, val))
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return found;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are asking is not possible, just consider that (obviously) `nullArray == null` is true.

Comment: You can create overload `In<T>(this T value, T arg1)`

Comment: @laika, I'm afraid that's not possible, as that would end up in an ambiguous call.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma both are `null`, I know. But if we had a type available for the literal `null` (let's just call it `NullType` for example), we could use it in a method overload, like `In<T>(this T value, NullType nullValue)`. As the literal `null` would be of type `NullType`, the call `nullString.In(null)` would invoke the above overload, instead of invoking `In<T>(T value, params T[] values)`.

Comment: This approach however, as far as I've searched, is also impossible. As Eric Lippert said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8215365/3653776) and [here](https://ericlippert.com/2013/07/25/what-is-the-type-of-the-null-literal), they "removed references to the useless 'null type' in the C# 3.0 specification.".

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing should be an edge case. There's no reason to pass a single untyped `null` to a method expecting a `params` argument. The only way it could happen is if you do it explicitly as you do in your example - hard-coding the `null` as the argument.

If you declare

```
string nullString = null;
```

or

```
object nullObject = null;
```

and pass either as the parameter, it will be understood as an array of one element which is null.

So the question arises - in what scenario would you want to declare a method that expects `params` and explicitly pass an untyped null?

If it did call the first method (`params`) as you want it to, it would always return `true`. Since you're hard-coding the null, why not replace

```
bool b1 = nullString.In(null);
```

with

```
var b1 = true;
```

---

Another way of looking at this, if you're concerned about how another developer might call your method:

If someone else calls `bool b1 = nullString.In(null)` then it should be obvious to them that what they're doing makes no sense. Remember, they have to do this *explicitly*. They have to hard-code it. The only reason to do that is if they're bored and feel like breaking something. You can throw them an `ArgumentNullException` and be done with it. They should not be even a little bit surprised when the method throws that exception. They should be surprised if it doesn't.

Comment: From that point of view, you are absolutely right. I'd never call `nullString.In(null)`, I'd just check if `nullString == null`. But the problem is that most of the time we are writing code for other developers to use, and unfortunately we can't control the way they code. We need to consider that just like in Murphy's law, any code that can be misused will be misused. The idea here is just to respond the best way we can. Since `T[]` and `IEnumerable<T>` are collections, we would like to treat them the same way.